get the value from the attribute using selectized funtion but they show null value
Title: Issue with retrieving data-tax-rate value in input field when using Selectize in Laravel
Question:
I am working with a Laravel application where I have a dropdown populated with items and their respective tax-rate attributes. I want to update the value of an input field with the tax-rate when an item is selected from the dropdown.
The problem I am facing is that when I use the Selectize library for the dropdown, the tax rate field does not update and instead shows null. However, when I do not use Selectize, it works properly.
Here is my code:
<!-- Include Selectize CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css" />

<!-- Your Select Dropdown -->
<select name="items[]" class="form-control section" onchange="updateTaxRate(this)">
    <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}" data-tax-rate="18">{{ $item->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>



function updateTaxRate(selectElement) {
    // Get the selected option element
    const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];
    
    // Retrieve the tax rate from the selected option's data attribute
    const taxRate = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-tax-rate');
    
    console.log("Tax rate from data attribute:", taxRate);

    // Find the closest 'tr' (table row) element
    const row = selectElement.closest('tr');
    
    // Find the tax rate input within this row
    const taxRateInput = row.querySelector('.tax_rate');
    
    if (taxRateInput) {
        // Set the tax rate input's value
        taxRateInput.value = taxRate;
    }
}


One way to get the data attribute after Selectize has modified the DOM is to use Selectize's API to retrieve the data. In this case, you can access the data-tax-rate value directly from Selectize using JavaScript.
Update your code as follows:
<!-- Include Selectize JS and CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your Select Dropdown -->
<select id="items" name="items[]" class="form-control section">
    <option value="" selected>Choose...</option>
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->id }}" data-tax-rate="{{ $item->tax_rate }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<!-- JavaScript to initialize Selectize and handle tax rate update -->
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const selectElement = document.getElementById('items');

        // Initialize Selectize on the dropdown
        const selectizeInstance = $(selectElement).selectize()[0].selectize;

        // Event listener for Selectize's change event
        selectizeInstance.on('change', function(value) {
            // Find the selected option based on the value
            const selectedOption = selectElement.querySelector(`option[value="${value}"]`);
            
            // Retrieve the tax rate from the selected option's data attribute
            const taxRate = selectedOption ? selectedOption.getAttribute('data-tax-rate') : null;

            console.log("Tax rate from data attribute:", taxRate);

            // Find the closest 'tr' (table row) element
            const row = selectElement.closest('tr');
            
            // Find the tax rate input within this row
            const taxRateInput = row.querySelector('.tax_rate');
            
            if (taxRateInput) {
                // Set the tax rate input's value
                taxRateInput.value = taxRate;
            }
        });
    });
</script>


Not Working In console they show null value but i want attribute value
output:
Tax rate from data attribute: null
